# Checking if queue is empty

Tags: c, queue

I'm new to C and I'm trying to code a queue problem.  At the moment, I'm coding something that will check if the queue is empty.  This is what I have so far:

For Queue.h (this was provided by our instructor)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct queueNode {
    char data;
    struct queueNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct queueNode QueueNode;
typedef QueueNode* QueueNodePtr;

typedef struct Queue {
    QueueNodePtr head;
    QueueNodePtr tail;
} Queue;

void instructions();
int isEmpty(Queue);
void enqueue(Queue*, char);
char dequeue(Queue*);
void printQueue(Queue);
void freeQueue(Queue*);
```

For Queue.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Queue.h"

int isEmpty(struct Queue queue)
 {
     if (Queue == NULL)
     {
         return 1;
     }
 }
```

The problem is in line 8 of Queue.c, the compiler says "error: expected expression before 'Queue'"  How will I resolve this?

Edit: I tried to use **queue == NULL** instead of **Queue == NULL** and the compiler said: error: invalid operands to binary == (have 'struct Queue' and 'void*').

Thank you very much!

Comment: `Queue` is the name of a struct.  The expression `Queue == NULL` is trying to compare a type name to a value.  The parameter `struct Queue queue` passes your queue by _value_, which might not be what you want.  All things considered, it's absolutely unclear how to answer this, as it probably depends on the semantics of your structure itself.  I suggest you edit your question to show the contents of `Queue.h`.

Comment: **Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), see this [C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), read the documentation of your compiler** (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) **and debugger** (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). With GCC compile as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug info). Take inspiration from *existing* programs coded in C on [github](http://github.com/)

Comment: Thank you for references!  They are indeed useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, use a consistent way of passing your queue around.  Note the differences in the interfaces:

```
int isEmpty(Queue);             //<-- by value
void enqueue(Queue*, char);     //<-- by reference
char dequeue(Queue*);           //<-- by reference
void printQueue(Queue);         //<-- by value
void freeQueue(Queue*);         //<-- by reference
```

Some of these are passing a Queue structure by value, and others by reference (pointer).  It's likely that you want all your functions to operate on a pointer, *i.e.* `Queue*`.

Next, you should have some kind of operation that initializes the queue.  You have `freeQueue` already, which does the inverse.  So you probably want something like `initQueue`:

```
void initQueue(Queue* q) {
    q->head = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;
}
```

Now, on to the actual question...  As I've already suggested, you should change `isEmpty` (and `printQueue`) to accept a *pointer* to the queue.  And then you use whatever logic should indicate the queue is empty.  Since I've asserted above that on initialization, the `head` pointer should probably be NULL, then that would be an appropriate "empty" test as well:

```
int isEmpty(Queue* q) {
    return q->head == NULL;
}
```

And finally, since you're likely to ask how to actually use this:

```
int main(void)
{
    Queue q;

    initQueue(&q);
    printf("Queue empty: %d\n", isEmpty(&q));

    enqueue(&q, 'X');
    printf("Queue empty: %d\n", isEmpty(&q));

    enqueue(&q, 'Y');
    enqueue(&q, 'Z');
    printQueue(&q);

    printf("Removed %c\n", dequeue(&q));
    printQueue(&q);

    freeQueue(&q);        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is very helpful!